# SSIS 2014 integrate SAP BW, MS Connector 1.1

Tags: sql, ssis, bids, sap-bw

I'm trying to setup the integration between SQL Server 2014 and SAP BW 7.3. I read a white paper but it was talking about SQL 2008 and MS Connector 1.0.

I'm using SSIS 2014 on VS 2012 with MS Connector 1.1 librfc32.dll is in system 32 folder.

When I'm trying to create a new connection on the Integration Services Project I can't find "SAP BW Source" nor I can find SAPBI connection in the new connection option!

As I've seen it should be between "OLEDB" and "SMOServer" and should say "SAPBI":

[image: New Connection Manager Options]

I have selected the SAP BW Components from the .NET Framework Components:

[image: .NET Components]

Also there's no "BW Source" as it should have in the source list of the SSIS Toolbox:

[image: source list of the SSIS Toolbox]

Please help! I'm lost, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem, a simple solution:

With SSIS 2014 VS 2013 needs to be used.

Comment: i was using VS 2012 , as soon as i tried it with 2013 everything was fine!